# What's a word like "posterity", but not for so long into the future?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word like "posterity". I was going to use it but it feels like too long into the future. I looked up the definition for posterity and got:

> succeeding or future generations collectively:

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/posterity)

I don't need for future generations, but rather for keeping for the next few years (5-10 years)?

I'm looking for an alternative that fits in place of the word posterity, because that's nice an concise. I thought of "for record keeping purposes" instead of "for posterity" but that doesn't feel as concise. Is there a word that I could use instead?

Here's my example sentence:

> "I've also attached the binary to this email for _ "

Comment: "for future reference"?

Comment: Why not just 'for the record'?

Comment: "For the file."

Comment: I always use "posterior".

Comment: I think the main reason to get rid of 'posterity' is because it's highfalutin'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps **for future reference** will work better for you:

> #### For Future Reference
>
> - For use at a later date.
>
> *"She lodged this idea in the back of her mind for future reference"*

([OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/for_future_reference))

Comment: If you just put "reference", as you can't go in the past to reference something, so it implies future use.

Comment: @Tim You can reference in the present, though.

Answer (score 0):

**For ‘the foreseeable future’**

...which implies ‘for an indeterminate amount of time into the future’ (presumably, as far forward as one can currently be bothered to look) but doesn’t have the finality of ‘posterity’.

https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/foreseeable